# How to Handle staleElementException which occurs randomly . In my case it throws the exception randomly

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using POM with Page Factory pattern to test my application . During the execution of the test i get staleElementException randomly i.e not at a specific element . I know it can be handled by putting ExpectedConditions.Refreshed(ExpectedCondition.VisiblityOfElement(Element)) statement but my problem is i need something comprehensive which should handle this exception irrespective of the element it appears . Currently If  it throws the exception then only i know that it may appear in this place . But can you guys suggest something which i can use before every element so that if it comes it will handle the exception else it dos nothing .

```
    public static boolean waitForElement(WebDriver driver, WebElement element, int maxWait) {

            boolean statusOfElementToBeReturned = false;
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, maxWait);
    try {
        WebElement waitElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));                   
        if (waitElement.isDisplayed() && waitElement.isEnabled()) {
            statusOfElementToBeReturned = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        statusOfElementToBeReturned = false;
    }
    return statusOfElementToBeReturned;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tested and verified solution like give below.

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
                           try{
                              WebElement e1 = driver.findelement(by.id("elementid"));

                              e1.click();\\do the respective operation on the element

                              break; \\break the for loop if element found in first 
                                       line.
                             }

 catch(StaleReferenceException ex){
                                  \\In case of element no found, driver will land in 
                                    this block.

}
}
```

try this solution and let me know if it works for you, stale reference exception occurs when the element reference is not found in the DOM or the element is attaching in the DOM after the driver passess through.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to accessing the element which is not present in [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) anymore.

Moreover calling [isDisplayed()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isDisplayed--) function on the element which is not present will result into [NoSuchElementException](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchElementException.html)

So I would recommend refactoring your code to look like:

```
public static boolean waitForElement(WebDriver driver, By by, int maxWait) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, maxWait);
    try {
        WebElement waitElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(by));
        if (waitElement.isDisplayed() && waitElement.isEnabled()) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or even better consider implementing [Page Object Model design pattern](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Design+Patterns+-+Page+Object+Model) as in this case [PageFactory](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageFactory) will take care of finding elements, waiting for elements, etc.

Comment: I am facing StaleElement Exception In pageFactory Pattern itself . But I have read couple of Blogs which says On PageFactory Design Pattern ,StaleEement Reference Exception will not be thrown as it follows Lazy loading machanism . But how am i getting it on POM pattern . I tried to overcome this by Putting a Catch block in WaitForElement method (i mentined above) since this method is called before every intercation with webElement ) and in the catch Block i am refreshing the page . But this also seems to be not working always